# Connection error rpc with Golang and DGraph

Tags: go, grpc, rpc, dgraph-dgo

i'm trying make a mutation inside a DGraph database, but when i run the code, it throws me the next error:

> rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection close exit status 1

I'm using dGraph with docker in the port 8000, my code of golang here:

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "context"
   "encoding/json"
   "log"
   dgo "github.com/dgraph-io/dgo"
   api "github.com/dgraph-io/dgo/protos/api"
   grpc "google.golang.org/grpc"
)

type Person struct {
   Name string `json:"name,omitempty"`
   Lastname string `json:"lastname,omitempty"`
}

func main() {
conn, err := grpc.Dial("localhost:8000", grpc.WithInsecure())
if err != nil {
  log.Fatal(err)
}
defer conn.Close()
dgraphClient := dgo.NewDgraphClient(api.NewDgraphClient(conn))
p := Person {
    Name: "Giovanni",
    Lastname: "Mosquera Diazgranados",
}
txn := dgraphClient.NewTxn()
ctx := context.Background()
defer txn.Discard(ctx)
pb, err := json.Marshal(p)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
mu := &api.Mutation{
    SetJson: pb,
}
res, err := txn.Mutate(ctx, mu)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Aqui toy")
    log.Fatal(err)
} else {
    fmt.Println(res)
}
}
```

How can i solve this error to connect with my DGraph and make a mutation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

To get your code working locally with the docker "standalone" version of DGraph I had to change 2 things:

- use port `9080`. The container exposes 3 ports: `8000`, `8080`, `9080`. Using `8080` or `8000` I get the same error you mentioned.
- use the `v2` imports. Not sure which version of DGraph server you are running, so you might not need to do this. But in case you have a new server you need these imports:

```golang
import (
    dgo "github.com/dgraph-io/dgo/v2"
    api "github.com/dgraph-io/dgo/v2/protos/api"
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the Welcome, i apreciate it

Comment: I tried changing to "github.com/dgraph-io/dgo/v2", but Go throws the next error: cannot find package "github.com/dgraph-io/dgo/v2" in any of:
        /usr/local/go/src/github.com/dgraph-io/dgo/v2 (from $GOROOT)
        /home/giovanni/go/src/github.com/dgraph-io/dgo/v2 (from $GOPATH)\nHow can i solve it?

Comment: Did you `go get` the new import path "github.com/dgraph-io/dgo/v2"?

Comment: Yeah, when i try "go get github.com/dgraph-io/dgo/v2", it throws the error: cannot find package "github.com/dgraph-io/dgo/v2" in any of: /usr/local/go/src/github.com/dgraph-io/dgo/v2 (from $GOROOT) /home/giovanni/go/src/github.com/dgraph-io/dgo/v2 (from $GOPATH)

Comment: I only can import the "github.com/dgraph-io/dgo" without the "v2"

Comment: `go get github.com/dgraph-io/dgo/v2` works perfectly for me. If you have go modules initialized you can also try a `go mod tidy` to get the dependencies.

Comment: But in any case: this has now become a dependency problem, not a dgraph/dgo problem any more.

Comment: I tried go mod tidy and the console say this: go: cannot find main module; see 'go help modules'... it means problems with my version of go or something?

Comment: Is there a go.mod file in the same folder as your project root? If not, go to that folder and call `go mod init` and give the module a name. The name is best domain based to be unique like `github.com/tehsphinx/somemodule`.

Comment: Now, i tried run main.go again and the program throws: txn:<start_ts:10005 keys:"2pfpqbr3tbesw" keys:"33c6sanwfh7vf" preds:"1-lastname" preds:"1-name" > latency:<parsing_ns:77135 processing_ns:212523532 assign_timestamp_ns:1301523 total_ns:214009218 > uids:<key:"dg.1102523270.1" value:"0x2711" >. this response 
means all right?

Comment: Yes, that is from `fmt.Println(res)`. It is the result of the mutation containing the uid and other information.

Comment: Ohh! Right!! Finally!. Now... can you help me with one more thing?... How can i view the mutation of data in the DGraph? I'm triying with the query: "data(func:has(name))" but this dont return anything...

Comment: Are you providing fields you want to see? like `name` and `lastname`. At least ask for uid. Example: `{
  data(func: has(name)) {
    uid
    name
  }
}`

Comment: Doing the tour might help you. It will use a local dgraph instance to run against and fill it with data in the first steps. Then you can play with the data right from the tour: https://dgraph.io/tour/intro/1/

Comment: I did not think that someone would answer a question of that language and also about its connection in DGraph, you are the god of Go, really, thank you very much!The program works perfectly, i'm really grateful with you, honestly

Comment: Thx :D Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Port `8000` is for the ratel-ui which comes with dgraph. To make mutations using the dgraph go client you will want to connect to the exposed grpc-alpha port, this is typically on `9080`.